# What is the difference between firebase-admin and @google-cloud/firestore npm packages?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working with Firestore database in my Node.js application, but I get confused with the different options to get the firestore client. In the past, I was using firebase-admin to connect to my firestore database and get the client, but then I found out I can also use the @google-cloud/firestore npm package to do the same thing.

**In their [@firebase/firestore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/firestore) package, they suggest you to use @google-cloud/firestore package:**

> This is the Cloud Firestore component of the Firebase JS SDK.
>
> This package is not intended for direct usage, and should only be used
> via the officially supported firebase package.
>
> If you are developing a Node.js application that requires
> administrative access to Cloud Firestore, use the
> @google-cloud/firestore Server SDK with your developer credentials.

**But in their [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) they suggest to use firebase-admin:**

> Set up your development environment Add the required dependencies and
> client libraries to your app.

> Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your app:
>
> `npm install firebase-admin --save`

Answer (score 1):

firebase-admin is just a thin wrapper around @google-cloud/firestore (among other products, under one umbrella).  They have the exact same API once you get a hold of a Firestore object. Use either one you want - there is no "correct" solution.

firebase-admin is intended to be easier to use for people already using other Firebase products on their backend. But you can decide what is easiest for you.

@firebase/firestore is meant for use in web applications and is not meant for use in nodejs apps.